# UTextView autocomplete vs live suggestions iOS

Tags: objective-c, autocomplete

If I turn the autocorrection ON, the words get autocompleted, as if I write "wor", I get "word" before I finish writing. I don't want this to happen because I might be writing "world" or any word different than the autocompleted one.

I set Correction off in the Interface Builder and this problem is solved.

The problem now is that I still need the suggestions that appear in a little popover below the incomplete words.

This two features might be different but I don't know how to activate the suggestions.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the UITextView TextViewDidChange I created a thread that changed the cursor position. This, off course happens after the text view changes. The change of the cursor position triggers the autocomplete without letting me even see that there had been a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with the use of tableview. Create a tableview with the width as of the width of the textfield and height as you like. Place it just below the textfield. Make it hidden initially. When the user starts typing, fetch the array of data that resembles to the typed text and if any exists then, unhide the table view. On the subsequent typing keep on reloading the tableview sections with animations. You should be accurate on hiding, unhiding and then reloading the data on the tableview. I have implemented such thing before. It is really easy and once you get started with it you find it easy.

Comment: But what happened? Is it that the new iOS version changed the live suggestions with the autocorrection?